# Typescript - Import type definition from one file to another

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given the following files, how do I import the definitions from bar.d.ts to foo.d.ts namespace?

My goal is to be able to import a module declaration to another, adding it to a namespace.

```
// bar.d.ts
declare module 'IBarService' {
    export function method (url: string): ng.IPromise<any>;
}

// foo.d.ts
/// <reference path="bar.d.ts" />

export as namespace Foo;

export = Foo;

declare namespace Foo {
    // import methods from IBarService. But how?
}
```

Any help would be great. Any insights about how to reuse custom definitions between different projects would be awesome as well.

Comment: did " import * as IBarService from 'IBarService'  " not work?  I had some difficulty importing from one d.ts to another - for some reason it made the importing module 'not found' in a 3rd ts file. That went away when I deleted the declare module block and just used the declare namespace.